# How can I delete array elements just once to add new ones with a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

What I am trying to do is:

1. set an array value (list) to another array (options).
2. If the user's input (searchVal) matches with a list value it will delete options, push this match, and then will keep pushing the next matches without deleting options again.

So according to the code below, if searchVal was `"whatever"`, options should return: `["whatever", "whatevEver1"]` but, instead, it returns: `["whatever", "WhatEver1", "whatttever", "whatever", "whatevEver1"]`

Relevant code:

```js
var list = ["whatever", "WhatEver1", "whatttever"];
var clear = 0;
var options = [];
    
    
for (var i=0 ; i < list.length ; i++)
{
    options.push([list[i]]);
}
    
var searchVal = window.prompt(" ");
     
for (var i=0 ; i < list.length ; i++)
{
    if (list[i].toLowerCase().includes(searchVal.toLowerCase())) {
        if (clear == 0) {
            options.length = 0; 
        }
        options.push([list[i]]);
    }
    clear++;
}

return options;
```

Comment: If I run your code, `options`'s value is `[ [ 'whatever', 'whatever' ], [ 'WhatEver1', 'WhatEver1' ] ]`.
Also, I would recommend to do `options = []` instead of truncating the length, but I say that without knowing additional details of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Js arrays are pass-by-reference. In order to make independent copy of array you need to use:

```
let options = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(list));
```

I didnt try to implement this to your problem cause im too lazy but i think it might work.